# Listing the IP addresses of a specific adapter only

Tags: powershell

I am very new to powershell and trying to write a script where I BIND my Websites and FTP sites on a server to the Ip addresses present on the specific adapter of a multihome server.

The server has two adapters: Primary and Secondary

I am using the following command:

```
 $AvailableIPs = @( Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -ne $Null } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress )
```

and this gets me all the IP addresses on the machine from primary as well as secondary.

I need to get the list if IP address only from the secondary adapter.
The situation that the Name of the secondary adapter will not be constant but the name of primary adapter will be constant so I would need to do a -ve match on the name of primary adapter.

How can I put two -ve matches in the same command?
Something like this does not work:

```
 $AvailableIPs = @( Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -ne $Null } | Where-Object { $_.Description -ne "<Primary Adapter Name>"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress )
```

What would be the syntax for getting the list from 
`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` Class which is not Null and which does not have the description of "Some name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the "sometext" to whatever you want...

```
$AvailableIPs = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | 
? {$_.IPEnabled -and $_.Description -notmatch "sometext"} | 
Select -ExpandProperty IPAddress
```

You don't need to use more then one `Where-Object` (`?` Alias) Clause, you can join them like in the above example,

Also you you can change the operator from `-notmatch` to `-ne` (Not Equal) if you have constant specific name

Comment: Thank you so much!
Works perfectly :)

Have upvoted your response, but looks like i nee some minumum points for that to get displayed

Comment: you welcome, to get more info, `get-help about_Comparison_operators` and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx